# Getting null reference exception when switching from one intent to another intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting null reference exception in the childActivity intent.I am newbie to the android development.Please help me to resolve this problem.What i am doing to sending data from ParentActivity to ChildActivity.

ParentActivity :I have 3 EditText fields in the ParentActivity.I want to display these 3 fields into ChildActivity.There is a button control so when i click on it,It has to switch from ParentActivity to ChildActivity.

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText EmpId;
    private EditText EmpName;
    private EditText Gender;
    private Button btnShowInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent);
        InitializeControls();
    }

    private void InitializeControls() {
        EmpId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EmpName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        btnShowInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Context context = this;
        btnShowInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent ParentIntent = new Intent(context, ChildActivity.class);

                ParentIntent.putExtra("Eid", EmpId.getText().toString());
                ParentIntent.putExtra("EName", EmpName.getText().toString());
                ParentIntent.putExtra("EGender", Gender.getText().toString());
                startActivity(ParentIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

ChildActivity :: It has to show the values which i entered in the ParentActivity.

```
public class ChildActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtView1;
    private TextView txtView2;
    private TextView txtView3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);
        InitializeControls();
    }

    private void InitializeControls() {
        txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txtView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        txtView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        GetDataFromIntent();
    }

    private void GetDataFromIntent() {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras == null) {
            txtView1.setText("No data is received.");
        } else {

            txtView1.setText(extras.getString("Eid"));
            txtView2.setText(extras.getString("EName"));
            txtView3.setText(extras.getString("EGender"));
        }
    }

}
```

Exception :: This is what i am getting in the Console window.

```
01-05 15:04:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(1658): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 15:04:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.example.androidexample1.ChildActivity.GetDataFromIntent(ChildActivity.java:36)
01-05 15:04:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.example.androidexample1.ChildActivity.InitializeControls(ChildActivity.java:26)
01-05 15:04:46.210: E/AndroidRuntime(1658):     at com.example.androidexample1.ChildActivity.onCreate(ChildActivity.java:19)
```

I am newbie to the android world.Please help on this.

Comment: Which line is 36 in Child Activity?

Comment: Can you post your child XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the line of code that is causing the issue is:

```
txtView1.setText(extras.getString("Eid"));
```

A null pointer exception essentially means that you are trying to call a function on something that's null. In this case, it could be either `txtView1` or `extras`. As you check to see if extra is null, it must in fact be the txtView1 that is null. Per [Android documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29), `findViewById` returns:

> Returns
>
> ```
> The view that has the given id in the hierarchy or null
> ```

Thus, if you misspelled your text labels, it could cause this problem. A good way to check is by adding this right before your error.

```
Log.v("Child","txtView1="+txtView1);
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the solution.My problem is resolved.I have one more doubt.Where should i add [Log.v("Child","txtView1="+txtView1);] this line in order to debug.just give some sample.Anyway thanks for your help..

Comment: Add it right before the null pointer error. It's usually how I work them out.